# WPF: Convert ImageSource to Stream

Tags: wpf, image, c#-4.0, stream

How to convert an image source with URI /ReferencedAssembly;component/default.png
to Stream?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
var uri = new Uri("/ReferencedAssembly;component/default.png", UriKind.Relative);
var streamInfo = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
var stream = streamInfo.Stream;
```